# How can I use edittext value in for loop?

Tags: string, for-loop, android-edittext, integer

Even though I convert the value from string to Integer it throws an error as

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question you said invalid int: "", it's an empty string not a number. you should check if it's an empty string first before converting to a number.

```
if (string != null && !string.isEmpty()) {
   // convert to number
}
```